# Strange mono-fixed-width font in Chromium, custom fonts has no effect

Tags: fonts, chromium

From time to times Chromium renders mono font in a weird way. The screenshot shows this page https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/21436#issuecomment-687815177 which is rendered correctly with Firefox.

I don't know how / when / why the issue occurs and don't know how to reproduce it. Sometimes, close Chromium and reopen fixes the issue. But today the problem survive all Chromium close/restart. Maybe I should reboot. EDIT: confirmed a reboot does fix the issue. But not sure how long it would last.

What is causing this issue? And, more importantly, is there any fix?

Env: Ubuntu 20.04.2, Chromium 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

[image: Chromium fails to render mono font]